grafana connecting datasource elasticsearch with index pattern
When trying to connect to elasticsearch 8.x from grafana 10.4.2 it works with indexes that do not have patterns.. For example
index_1 = success
But
index_1.2024.05.11 fails , even when I select "Pattern Daily"
From what I can tell its a malformed request.
Get \"http://192.168.86.77:9200/c12amnn65/11/2024_0tamti0tic0_5/11/2024dex-/_mapping\": 400 Bad Request" 

If I select an index that has no pattern then it works fine. Do I have to add some type of regex?
Side note. It works fine with datastreams im guessing because those have no patterns.

ok so the answer is do index_1* and select NO pattern. Doesn't seem intuitive to me but that worked
